# How to set Apache configurations in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I build a small project and it s working fine in Localhost, but not in a Share Hosting because of some configurations in the Apache config file.
Because this Hosting Service doesn't allow access to **httpd.conf** file, i could only use .htaccess file to do it.

My config in the local environnent:

```
<Directory "/path/to/the/site/directory/">
   Options Indexes 
   FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have tried to use a htaccess file like below:

```
 Options -Indexes 
 FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
 AllowOverride All   //seems not to be working
 Require all granted
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help. Thanks so much.

Comment: [AllowOverride directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is not allowed in [.htaccess context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context)

Comment: Ok that's right. Thanks for the link. I dont really know i could manage with this.

Comment: It depends what your Hoster allows you. On a shard Hosting system you never have access to the Server configuration. If you Hoster allow All or some options you can place them in you .htaccess file.  AllowOverride All is not allowed in your .htaccess file only in the Server Vitualhost config.